# Receive NPE when I want to create the Field with type StandardSQLTypeName.ARRAY in Google BigQuery

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I get the NPE whenever I want to create a Field with the ARRAY type in BQ, I investigate a source code and understand that the Legacy Type does not have an ARRAY type.

Please help me, maybe I can create an array typed field in other ways?

[image: Source screenshot]

[image: Code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and instead of doing

```
Field.of("name", StandardSQLTypeName.ARRAY)
```

(which I also got an NPE on)

I did

```
Field.newBuilder("name", StandardSQLTypeName.STRING).setMode(Field.Mode.REPEATED).build()
```